# Control key doesn't work and the down arrow became the control key

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mojave

A strange thing happened 3 days ago, where my keyboard stopped working suddenly. I restarted the laptop and then I couldn't type anything, not even my password.

After some hours I realized that the <kbd>control</kbd> key was somehow enabled the whole time and that's why I couldn't do anything.

So I disabled the <kbd>control</kbd> key from the keyboard settings and 
it worked for some minutes, but then the same problem happened again.
I enabled the sticky keys feature and saw the control still enabled.

After I while I noticed that the down arrow key behaved as if it were the control key.

**Specs:** MacBook Pro Retina 2015 running macOS Mojave

**Note:** I've tried restoring, but now the keyboard shortcuts don't work anymore while booting up, not even booting from the USB.

**QUESTION:** How can I troubleshoot this further to fix my keyboard?

Comment: What other apps do you have to control the key board? using external USB cable keyboard might help for now, and allow you to fix the problem.

Comment: @Buscar웃 the same behavior was found while using an external Keyboard